# How to divide rows with a certain number and other rows with the sum in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to divide Custom Codes 200-940 with their respective sales while custom codes "100 Cashiers" and "950 Front Office Admin" with the total of all sales. Please we image as I'm sure it will make a lot more sense when one sees it. Custom Codes is a column, Total Labor and Total Sales are both measures
[image]

I tried using a if statement =

```
if('Total Sales' > 0, 'Total Labor'/'Total Sales, 'Total Labor'/sum(SalesAmnt)
```

..SalesAmnt is where the majority of the sales come from but it isn't the sum of all sales, 'Total Sales' is the sum of all sales. This didn't pull the sum but only would divide by the row

```
Column = if(JobCodes[Custom Codes] = "100 Cashiers" || "950 Front Office Admin", 'RSMDetail'[Total Labor]/sum('Ace Daily Sales'[Net Sales]), 'RSMDetail'[Total Labor]/'RSMDetail'[Total Sales])
```

Also tried this but the error "Cannot convert value '950 Front Office Admin' of type Text to type True/False." comes back

[image: Mapping]
[image: Table]
[image: Updated Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new Measure like this, assuming your measures are named as they are in your table visualization:

```
Labor Utilization = 
IF ( 
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Job Codes'[Custom Codes] ) 
        IN { "100 Cashier" , "950 Front Office Admin" } ,
    DIVIDE (
        [Total Labor] , 
        CALCULATE ( 
            [Total Sales] , 
            ALL ( 'Job Codes' )
        )
    ),
    DIVIDE ( 
        [Total Labor] ,
        [Total Sales]
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Marcus, this solution only returns the correct percentage for 950 Front Office Admin but not 100 Cashier, please see image attached to the original question.

Comment: Sorry, in my answer it is `Cashiers` in plural - fix that and you should be good. I will amend my answer.

Comment: The current answer should be good to go! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula:

```
Column =
IF (
    JobCodes[Custom Codes] = "100 Cashiers"
    || JobCodes[Custom Codes] = "950 Front Office Admin",
    'RSMDetail'[Total Labor]
        / SUM ( 'Ace Daily Sales'[Net Sales] ),
    'RSMDetail'[Total Labor] / 'RSMDetail'[Total Sales]
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Peter, I have tried your solution but it doesn't work. For example, 200 Grocery labor/sales = 2.80% but your solution shows 0.15%, this error is consistent through the table.

Comment: At least it doesn't throw an error. But where's your copyable sample data then? I can't check the formula ...

Comment: This is client data, unfortunately I can't share this. Could there be a work around?

Comment: This is what [minimal, reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) are for.

Answer (score 0):

This is my odd: Please test this one:

```
Column =
IF (
    JobCodes[Custom Codes] = "100 Cashiers"
        || JobCodes[Custom Codes] = "950 Front Office Admin",
    'RSMDetail'[Total Labor]
        / CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Ace Daily Sales'[Net Sales] ), ALL ( 'Ace Daily Sales' ) ),
    'RSMDetail'[Total Labor] / 'RSMDetail'[Total Sales]
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Ozan Sen, however, this only returns for 100 Cashiers and no other codes. Total Labor and Total Sales are both measures if that helps any

Comment: It changes the game . Also It seems that you have 2 Tables: Ace Daily Sales which I guess is a fact table, and JobCodes which is a dimension table! There is a Sales Amt Column in your Ace Daily Sales. Please share data from both tables , and your model view!

Comment: I have added two photos to the original post hopefully that helps. I also have a demo report I could send you on an email or something, whatever is easier for you. 
Total Labor = sum('Timeclock'[Regular]) + sum('Timeclock'[Overtime])............Total Sales = sum('Walmart Sales'[Walmart Sales]) + sum('RSMDetail'[Sales])